# How to handle groovy ambiguous method overload gracefully

Tags: groovy

I know there are similar questions but the answers are not satisfying.

I get an Groovy ambiguous method overload error when calling a method with null as parameter.

e.g.:

```
class A{
    sampleMethod (B bObj){
        if(bObj == null) {
            handleNullArgumentGracefully()
        }
        ... do some cool stuff ...
    }

    sampleMethod (C cObj){
        ... do some other cool stuff ...
    }
}
```

now when i call `sampleMethod(null)` groovy does not know which method it should invoke. Thats clear **but** is there a possibility to set one method of these two as **default method** to handle such null calls? I want to handle this on the **callee** side and **not** on the **caller** side (i do not want to cast something on the caller side)

**UPDATE:**
i found a solution how it could work but i don´t know why: convert the non default method to a closure property

```
class app {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def a = new A()
        a.sampleMethod(new B())
        a.sampleMethod(new C())
        a.sampleMethod(null)
    }
}

class A {
    def sampleMethod(B bObj = null) {
        if (bObj == null) {
            println("handle null")
        }
        println("1")
    }

    def sampleMethod = { C cObj ->
        println("2")
    }
}

class B {

}

class C {

}
```

Comment: You can modify one method  like 'sampleMethod(B bObj = null)' . So this method will get called even the if bObj is null

Comment: thanks i will try that :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following will fail with `Ambiguous method overloading for method A#sampleMethod`

```
class A{
    def sampleMethod (Number o=null){
        println "num $o"
    }

    def sampleMethod (String o){
        println "str $o"
    }
}

new A().sampleMethod(null)
```

this one will work (Object will be called for null):

```
class A{
    def sampleMethod (Number o=null){
        println "num $o"
    }

    def sampleMethod (String o){
        println "str $o"
    }

    def sampleMethod(Object o){
        println "obj $o"
    }
}

new A().sampleMethod(null)
```

but i like this one:

```
class A{
    def _sampleMethod (Number o){
        println "num $o"
    }

    def _sampleMethod (String o){
        println "str $o"
    }

    def sampleMethod(Object o){
        if(o==null){
            println "null"
            return null
        }else if(o instanceof Number){
            return _sampleMethod ((Number) o)
        }else if(o instanceof String){
            return _sampleMethod ((String) o)
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong argument type: ${o.getClass()}")
    }
}

new A().sampleMethod(null)
```

Comment: nice :)
can you explain why my updated question works?

Comment: that's because the second method declared as a closure variable (not really a method).

when groovy tries to find method for null - there is only one method - so no exception. for `C` it tries to find method - not found, so it looks for closure variables - there is a one.

//btw. in this case you don't need `B bObj = null`

Comment: thanks :) did not know the exact lookup sequence when groovy tries to find a method. Yeah taht `= null` default was just for testing